# Framework specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I noticed that there are a lot of framework specific tags for different MVC frameworks on stack**overflow**. Some examples:

- [`symfony-routing`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony-routing/info)
- [`yii-routing`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yii-routing/info)
- [`zend-framework-routing`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-framework-routing/info) (also available are [`zend-route`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-route/info) and [`zend-router`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-router/info))
- [`laravel-routing`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel-routing/info)

`routing` is one example but the same issue for things like `validation`, `input-filters` and a lot of other common MVC elements.

I have to say that when I ask a question related to Zend Framework 2 and routing I would most likely tag my question as [`zend-framework2`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-framework2/info) + [`routing`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/routing/info) just like all [these people did in their questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework2+routing+-zend-route+-zend-framework-routing+-zend-router).

I do this since the routing tags don't specify to which version of Zend Framework they relate to (version 1 or 2, soon also 3). And it is not desirable to introduce a new `zend-framework2-routing` and `zend-framework3-routing` for this purpose.

- What is the concept behind these framework specific tags? Or is it one of those nasty things that unexpectedly found its way into the system?
- Is the community supposed to use or avoid them?
- What about versioning, should different framework versions have their own tags? Or should all versions use one general tag?

Would it be an idea to help users more to find the right tags. So for example automatically exchange a tag `zend-framework-routing` with `zend-framework` + `routing` (or the opposite) or make suggestions for alternatives to the given tags? Or is this going to frustrate the users?